# HTML CSS Formatting

Tags: html, css

The bottom paragraph on this HTML page is not following the other `<p>` in this HTML site. It may be because I forgot to end something, but I don't know.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body style=";">
<head>
<body background="https://images.rapgenius.com/92abc49a4468f440d86e3c66541f0a2b.1000x991x1.jpg">
<title>Video Editor As A Career</title>
<style>
header{
background-color: #c6c6c6;
padding: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 35px;
color: black;
}
p {
 
color: red;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Helvetica;
 
}


nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 40%;
  overflow: auto;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
section:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  padding: 20;
 }
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  nav, article {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
  }

</head>
</style>
<body>
<header style="font-family:comic sans ms;"><u><b>Video Editor As A Career</b></u></header>
<section>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://app.myblueprint.ca/" target="_self">MyBlueprint </a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname1">The Role of A Video Editor</a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname">Software</a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname2">Requirements To Be A Video Editor</a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname3">What Does A Video Editor Do</a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname6">Colleges and Universities</a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname5">Demand</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div style="margin-left:25%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
<article>
<a name="targetname1"></a>
<h1  style="color:white;"> <center><b>The Role of A Video Editor</b></center></h1>
<p style="color:white;"> Have you ever seen any of those flashy commercials advertising a brand new product or a very high quality video on Youtube? Chances are is that the video was created by a video editor. Large companies like Microsoft or Cheerios have dedicateds video editors to make their new products look the best, sometimes even better! A video editor must attend either a University, College or Apprenticeship, which would have to be related to film. </p>
<a href="url">link text</a> 
<br>
<br>
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<br>
<a name="targetname"></a>
<h1  style="color:white;"> <center><a style="color:white;" href="https://searchmicroservices.techtarget.com/definition/software"><b> Software</b></a></center></h1>
<p style="color:white;">Of course to edit videos you need some sort of software. Professionals use software such as Adobe Premiere or Vegas Pro 16 (older versions of these softwares are not to shabby). In theses softwares you are able to add keyframes, trim/cut the video and many other stylish features. Also a part of video editing is editing audio. For smaller companies you may be asked to not only to edit the video, but also edit the audio. This is no problem with Audacity which is free! </p>
<a href="https://www.audacityteam.org/">
  <img src="https://www.audacityteam.org/wp-content/themes/wp_audacity/img/logo.png" width"150" height="150"></a>
<a href="https://www.vegascreativesoftware.com/ca/vegas-pro/">
  <img align="right" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/0/0a/Sony_Vegas_Pro_14_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20160925095337" width"150" height="150"></a>
<br>
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<br>
<a name="targetname2"></a>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<caption  style="color:white;font-size:150%;" align="top"> <b>Requirements To Be A Video Editor</b></caption>
<tr><center>
<th bgcolor="#ffffcc"> A Masters Degree In Film Production</th>
<th bgcolor="#ffffcc"> Film Degree </th>
<th bgcolor="#ffffcc"> A Bachelor's Degree of Fine Arts</th></center>
<tr>
</table>

<br>
<p style="color:white;"> Video/film editing could be very profitable. The best of the best were able to make over $120,000! In Ontario the provincial average is $49,000, but with a high of $76,000. There is also other ways to make money such as websites like Youtube, Vimeo, Instagram and many other social platforms which would allow you to make money from ads on the website. Some have been able to make these video editing on these sites a full time job and have been very profitable!
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<center>
<a name="targetname3"></a>
<h1  style="color:white;">What Does A Video Editor Do?<h1>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lRgLUTXnZ6I" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</center>
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<center>
<a name="targetname6"></a>
<h1  style="color:white;"><b>Colleges and Universities With Editing/Film Courses</b><h1>
<br>
<a href="http://sites.utoronto.ca/ic/mediaproduction/index.html">
<img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQE2yEMrkNmDVw/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=b_kXBEkvYUuMueM85D5Il458Ekzgy8OEj5SPITi6P8w"></a>
<a href="https://www.okanagan.bc.ca/home.html">
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/322923752/OKCollegeCol_400x400.gif" height="200px" width="200px" ></a>
<a href="https://stanfordvideo.stanford.edu/editing/">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/b7/Stanford_University_seal_2003.svg/1200px-Stanford_University_seal_2003.svg.png" height="200px" width="200px"></center></a>
<br>
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<br>
<center><h1  style="color:white;"><b>The Life Of A Film/Video Editor</b><h1>
<a name="targetname5"></a>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rB2_KSKVzko" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<center><h2  style="color:white;font-size:100%"><b>Companies Which Need Video/Editors</b><h2></center>
<a name="targetname6"></a>


**/Here is where the problem is, from here on down/**
<p1 style="color:white;font-size:50%"> Companies which currently require Video/Film editing services include, Universal needs a Graphic Designer and Animation Specialist. Also, Disney needs a Multiplatform Editor. So if you ever wanted to work in the movie business, maybe video editing is your way to go. A company more local, Pureblink requires an Editor/Motion Graphics Designer. There are many more opportunities for Video Editors everywhere!</p1>
<br>
<br>

<br>
<a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aQuvpDcgxcoy45znGfEmRkKa02G1ZLSHat8UY_cW5Ys/edit?usp=sharing">Work Cited Page</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add clear explanation? what do you mean not following the page?

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your HTML, apart from the errors pointed out by the answers. May I suggest running your page though a validator, such as the one at https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2):

Charis is right - the p1 tags at the bottom are the problem.  Paragraph tags are marked with p - not p1, p2, p3, etc like headline tags i.e. h1, h2, h3, etc.  This is what Charis was talking about.

As long as you replace the starting and closing p1 tags with p tags you'll be good to go.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body style=";">
<head>
<body background="https://images.rapgenius.com/92abc49a4468f440d86e3c66541f0a2b.1000x991x1.jpg">
<title>Video Editor As A Career</title>
<style>
header{
background-color: #c6c6c6;
padding: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 35px;
color: black;
}
p {
 
color: red;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Helvetica;
 
}


nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 40%;
  overflow: auto;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
section:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  padding: 20;
 }
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  nav, article {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
  }

</head>
</style>
<body>
<header style="font-family:comic sans ms;"><u><b>Video Editor As A Career</b></u></header>
<section>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://app.myblueprint.ca/" target="_self">MyBlueprint </a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname1">The Role of A Video Editor</a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname">Software</a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname2">Requirements To Be A Video Editor</a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname3">What Does A Video Editor Do</a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname6">Colleges and Universities</a></li>
<li><a href="#targetname5">Demand</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div style="margin-left:25%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
<article>
<a name="targetname1"></a>
<h1  style="color:white;"> <center><b>The Role of A Video Editor</b></center></h1>
<p style="color:white;"> Have you ever seen any of those flashy commercials advertising a brand new product or a very high quality video on Youtube? Chances are is that the video was created by a video editor. Large companies like Microsoft or Cheerios have dedicateds video editors to make their new products look the best, sometimes even better! A video editor must attend either a University, College or Apprenticeship, which would have to be related to film. </p>
<a href="url">link text</a> 
<br>
<br>
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<br>
<a name="targetname"></a>
<h1  style="color:white;"> <center><a style="color:white;" href="https://searchmicroservices.techtarget.com/definition/software"><b> Software</b></a></center></h1>
<p style="color:white;">Of course to edit videos you need some sort of software. Professionals use software such as Adobe Premiere or Vegas Pro 16 (older versions of these softwares are not to shabby). In theses softwares you are able to add keyframes, trim/cut the video and many other stylish features. Also a part of video editing is editing audio. For smaller companies you may be asked to not only to edit the video, but also edit the audio. This is no problem with Audacity which is free! </p>
<a href="https://www.audacityteam.org/">
  <img src="https://www.audacityteam.org/wp-content/themes/wp_audacity/img/logo.png" width"150" height="150"></a>
<a href="https://www.vegascreativesoftware.com/ca/vegas-pro/">
  <img align="right" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/0/0a/Sony_Vegas_Pro_14_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20160925095337" width"150" height="150"></a>
<br>
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<br>
<a name="targetname2"></a>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<caption  style="color:white;font-size:150%;" align="top"> <b>Requirements To Be A Video Editor</b></caption>
<tr><center>
<th bgcolor="#ffffcc"> A Masters Degree In Film Production</th>
<th bgcolor="#ffffcc"> Film Degree </th>
<th bgcolor="#ffffcc"> A Bachelor's Degree of Fine Arts</th></center>
<tr>
</table>

<br>
<p style="color:white;"> Video/film editing could be very profitable. The best of the best were able to make over $120,000! In Ontario the provincial average is $49,000, but with a high of $76,000. There is also other ways to make money such as websites like Youtube, Vimeo, Instagram and many other social platforms which would allow you to make money from ads on the website. Some have been able to make these video editing on these sites a full time job and have been very profitable!
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<center>
<a name="targetname3"></a>
<h1  style="color:white;">What Does A Video Editor Do?<h1>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lRgLUTXnZ6I" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</center>
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<center>
<a name="targetname6"></a>
<h1  style="color:white;"><b>Colleges and Universities With Editing/Film Courses</b><h1>
<br>
<a href="http://sites.utoronto.ca/ic/mediaproduction/index.html">
<img src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQE2yEMrkNmDVw/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=b_kXBEkvYUuMueM85D5Il458Ekzgy8OEj5SPITi6P8w"></a>
<a href="https://www.okanagan.bc.ca/home.html">
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/322923752/OKCollegeCol_400x400.gif" height="200px" width="200px" ></a>
<a href="https://stanfordvideo.stanford.edu/editing/">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/b7/Stanford_University_seal_2003.svg/1200px-Stanford_University_seal_2003.svg.png" height="200px" width="200px"></center></a>
<br>
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<br>
<center><h1  style="color:white;"><b>The Life Of A Film/Video Editor</b><h1>
<a name="targetname5"></a>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rB2_KSKVzko" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<hr size=6 width=675 color="white">
<center><h2  style="color:white;font-size:100%"><b>Companies Which Need Video/Editors</b><h2></center>
<a name="targetname6"></a>


**/Here is where the problem is, from here on down/**
<p style="color:white;font-size:50%"> Companies which currently require Video/Film editing services include, Universal needs a Graphic Designer and Animation Specialist. Also, Disney needs a Multiplatform Editor. So if you ever wanted to work in the movie business, maybe video editing is your way to go. A company more local, Pureblink requires an Editor/Motion Graphics Designer. There are many more opportunities for Video Editors everywhere!</p>
<br>
<br>

<br>
<a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aQuvpDcgxcoy45znGfEmRkKa02G1ZLSHat8UY_cW5Ys/edit?usp=sharing">Work Cited Page</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But then why is the last paragraph still bolded?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem - some of your headline elements don't have a closing tag.  In this case, the "The Life Of A Film/Video Editor" h1 doesn't have a /h1 closing tag at the end of it, so this bottom paragraph is being styled as an h1 and becoming bold.  Your first few headlines are closed properly, but starting at 'What Does A Video Editor Do', each headline is missing the '/' in the closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

p1 tag that you use seems wrong.p element is not used as h element to have different "deegrees" based on the size you want to create.

Comment: What do you mean by this? I removed the p1 tag and replaced it with <p>.

Comment: Also, is there anything affecting this paragraph by not ending a command or something?